# RESTFUL API in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I want to create restful api for hadoop which will be called from my front-end. Basically the api will call mapreduce program which will process my hbase data and will response JSON. I don't how to do this. Any useful resource will be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by creating a RESTful service using JPA(Java Persistance API), see [here](https://spinspire.com/article/combining-jpa-and-jax-rs-create-restful-service) and [here](https://matthiaswessendorf.wordpress.com/2010/03/17/apache-hadoop-hbase-plays-nice-with-jpa/), these are good links to get started with JPA.

Answer (score 0):

Well Map reduce will be taking time to run. They are designed to run as batch process. So your REST API would take good time, fopr the output to be ready.

Moreover the output of Map reduce would be a state(output written to files in a file system(HDFS)). So you cant return JSON with it. You should be reading the files
Please revisit the design you are planning. Happy learning